# Knockout Validation ko.validation.group vs ko.validatedObservable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

What is the difference in `ko.validation.group` and `ko.validatedObservable`? Are there particular situations when I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ko.validation.group` just gives you an (computed) observable of all the error messages in a model.  It only collects error messages of direct properties of the model.

The `ko.validatedObservable` on the other hand not only collects the error messages, but also wraps the model in an observable and adds an `isValid` property which indicates whether or not there are any error messages (i.e., the model was completely valid).  Otherwise, they're essentially the same.

If you're only interested in collecting the error messages, the `ko.validation.group` should be more than enough.  If you need an observable that keeps track of whether or not the model is valid, the `ko.validatedObservable` does some of the work for you.